# Which jQuery multimedia plugin?

Tags: image, jquery-plugins, video

I'm looking for a plugin to display images and videos in a Lightbox style. It should support the various formats, both in the local server and remote, such as from Youtube. Now I'm using CeeBox [http://catcubed.com/2008/12/23/ceebox-a-thickboxvideobox-mashup], but it supports only .swf videos. Making some web searches, I've found 
[prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) and [YoxView](http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/) which are both interesting. 

Could you suggest me which one of these two plugins is better or another one? 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/), as long as other JQuery Tools projects is a great tool

Comment: But I'm looking for a plugin both for images and for videos, isn't FlowPlayer just a video player?